# Android listview fetch the data from sqlite database

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to develop a small project in android SQlite..

I want to store en employees information to the database..
the fields are name,city,mail id and phone number..

Then I want to fetch the data in the List-view ..It will show by employees name..
When I click the name(another intent) It will show all the information of that name.

I have create DB helper class,and I can store the information..But I am unable to retrieve the database by name..can anyone help me?????

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static final String DATABASE = "contactapp.db";
static final int VERSION = 1;
static final String TABLE = "contact";

static final String C_ID = "_id";
static final String C_ENAME = "ename";
static final String C_city = "city";
static final String C_phno = "ph_no";


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSION);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ( " + C_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + C_ENAME + " text, "
            + C_city + " text, " + C_phno + " integer )");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


    db.execSQL("Drop table " + TABLE);


    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

and the management.java  which store the name,city and phone number in the sqlite database..

```
public class Management extends Activity {
EditText tname,tcity,tph_no;
Button button1;
DBHelper helper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.management);
    helper = new DBHelper(this);
    tname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tname);
    tcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tcity);
    tph_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tph_no);
    button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {


        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int s2=Integer.parseInt(tph_no.getText().toString());

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DBHelper.C_ENAME, tname.getText().toString());
            values.put(DBHelper.C_city, tcity.getText().toString());
            values.put(DBHelper.C_phno, s2);


            db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE, null, values);
            db.close();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Employee Added Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




    }
    });
}
```

}

now I want to retrieve/fetch only the name as a list..when I click the name it will go to the another intent and will show the name(again),city and phone number..

Comment: Post something useful code then.

Comment: share whatever you have done so far

Comment: for that you need Custom `ListView` and `Adapter`,,this [link](http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-list-view-using-custom-adapter.html) will help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#cursor)

> 1. `SimpleCursorAdapter`
>      In case you work directly with the database you can use the `SimpleCursorAdapter` to
>      define the data for your ListView.